# Extract video from streaming

Tags: scala, ffmpeg, video-streaming, live-streaming

Imagine a live video being streamed from a HD Camera to a computer. I would like to place markers at various moment on this stream in order to extract the content between markers to a file.

I am familiar with Scala but I could considere looking at any other technology do to the job.

Any idea on how to get started with this crazy idea ? :D

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do..

Try maybe use NodeJs - create readStream and mark the data on the fly. Or maybe save it to a temp file and mess with it in offline mode.

There is an npm package that expose the ffmpeg api to nodejs (https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) so you could use ffmpeg functions on your stream.

Comment: I want to mark a video on the fly and when i decide it (or when I have an opening and a closing tag, i want to extract this part of the video while it is still streaming the rest of the content